# spatie/laravel-permission remove permission from a role only for a particular user

Tags: laravel

i have 2 roles **writer** and **admin**.

**writer** role has permission to create article, edit article, delete  article

how can I remove the **create article** permission for a specified user without removing removing it from the **writer** role ?

Answer (score 0):

Roles and permissions are not necessarily the same thing. In the Spatie library you mentioned, you can use roles to group different permissions to make it easier for you to manage them.

So instead of you assigning different permissions to every single user like "can-create-post," "can-edit-post," etc., you create a role, for example, "publisher," and assign the permissions to that role, then assign the role to the user you want.

If I were you, I would create the "Writer" role like you mentioned, assign it the RUD (read, update, delete) permissions, and assign that role to the users who should have that ability. On top of that, in the admin panel, I would have a checkbox or something similar where the admin can tick "Can create article." If it's ticked, on the backend, what would be called is:

```
    $user->assignRole('writer');
    $user->givePermissionTo('create-article');
```

If not, then it would be just the

```
$user->assignRole('writer');
```

And if you ever wanted to edit a user and remove his ability to create posts, you would open hi profile in the admin panel and untick the checkbox which would call the

```
$user->revokePermissionTo('create-article');
```

Hope this was of help :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
but what if I have multi-resource (article, comments,posts etc.) **writer** must have the ability to create any resource. But I can disable the permission to create any type of resource at any time . in this case I think I can't use roles ?

Comment: What about using only **Direct Permissions** without **roles** ? (I want a production-ready solution)

Comment: Yes, you don't have to use roles at all and stick to just permissions. The way the library works is that when it checks if a user has a permission to do something, it goes to two different tables and checks: models_roles -> does user X have any roles? Yes it does, i'm gonna check what permissions are associated with that role. 
After that it goes to the models_permissions table and checks the same thing.
Look at the design here https://drawsql.app/templates/laravel-permission

Comment: If you want to handle differently each type of resource, then I would create multiple RUD roles (comments, articles etc..) and have separate different "create comment", "create article" etc permission. So if I at some point want to enable some John for example to be able to just create comments and articles but not posts I can call

$user->givePermissionTo('create comments');
$user->givePermissionTo('create articles');

That gives exclusivity to the create functionality and enables you to control who can create what resource

Answer (score 0):

A permission can be revoked from a user:

```php
$user->revokePermissionTo('create article');
```

you can checkout the documentation of Spatie for more information about [Direct Permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/direct-permissions)

Comment: It's not working, you can try it. 
If the user has a writer role, witch has permission to create, edit , delete articles , if you revoke the delete article permissions from ** the user **   it won't be deleted. Because he had the writer role witch still has permission to delete articles

Comment: you're right, revoking a permission from a user does not affect the permissions assigned to the role. So, the **writer** role will still have the **create article** permission.

therefore In this case, you will need to remove the permission from the role itself (which is not recommended) or don't assign the **writer** role to this specific user and just give it the expected permissions.